# What is wrong with using object as a type in Python?

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

The following program works, but gives a MyPy error:

```py
from typing import Type, TypeVar, Any, Optional


T = TypeVar('T')


def check(element: Any, types: Type[T] = object) -> Optional[T]:
    if not isinstance(element, types):
        return None
    return element


print(check(123, int))
print(check(123, object))
```

MyPy complains:

```
main.py:7: error: Incompatible default for argument "types" (default has type "Type[object]", argument has type "Type[T]")
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Replacing `object` with `Type[object]` mysteriously works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the default value has to fit for every possible substitution for `T`.  Since it doesn't the right way to solve this is to define overloads, one with the `Type[T]` producing `Optional[T]` and one with `Literal[object]` and producing `Any`.  Then in the combined declaration, the default can be provided.

This was addressed by Guido [here](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/3737).

Answer (score 0):

You're using the [type variable](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html?highlight=typing#typing.TypeVar) in the wrong place, it should be used with `element` not `types`.

```py
from typing import Optional, Type, TypeVar

T = TypeVar('T')

def check(element: T, types: Type = object) -> Optional[T]:
    if not isinstance(element, types):
        return None
    return element
```